# Login failed: No OpenID endpoint found

Tags: .net, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I want to set up my own OAuth Provider App. But I am struggling getting started.

I go to the consumer app on my localhost which is hosted on port via VS. And I select the option below

Interop with Service Provider sample using WCF w/ OAuth

I get redirected to the login on the Service Provdier. What do I login with

is it? http://localhost:65169/openidprovider/arnott/provider

I am using the default database and I have set the localhost in the whitelist

Cheers Chris

Answer (score 0):

To login you have to should use the base URL of the OpenId Provider application, in your case I presume its http :// localhost:65169/